# Not able to set row number by ordered by datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, row-number

I currently try to give my rows in the following table an index

```
    ticket_id(bigint)       val(nvarchar(4000)) 
    99856                   15.01.2019 16:58    
    99856                   15.01.2019 17:20    
    99921                   15.01.2019 17:31    
    100197                  16.01.2019 09:55
```

The index should've been generated by the following logic

```
    row_number() over (Partition by ticket_id Order by convert(datetime,val,104) asc) as nr
```

However, this query returns

> > The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

It works when I use the following query

```
    row_number() over (Partition by cast(ticket_id as int) Order by convert(datetime,val,104) asc) as nr
```

Can someone explain why?

Comment: use proper datatype in your column it will work everwhere

Comment: Change `val` to a date type, preferably `datetime2(0)`. The actual problem is the use of a text field to store date values instead of the proper type. In this case `datetime` or `datetime2(0)`. That's a *very big* design problem. It's way too easy to mix the formats and that particular format can't be sorted and indexed except as text.

Comment: Are you *sure* all `val` values are dates? It could be names, numbers or dates stored in different formats. You'll have to use `TRY_PARSE` or `TRY_CONVERT` to find data that matches the type and format you want.

Comment: Based on that `ticket_id` I suspect the table is for an issue tracking system that needs to track arbitrary data. You don't have to use a single text field for that. SQL Server provides [sparse columns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns?view=sql-server-2017) when there are a large number of optional fields. You could even use the [sql_variant](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/sql-variant-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) type although that would cause issues with ODBC. At least you wouldn't have to store dates as text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not correct conversion, try find bad values

```
SELECT * FROM [youTable] WHERE TRY_CONVERT(datetime,val,104) IS NULL
```

upd

> when I apply "Try_convert", I do not get any Error

**TRY_CONVERT**

```
Return Types
Returns a value cast to the specified data type if the cast succeeds; otherwise, returns null.
```

for example

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetime,'99.99.9999',104)
```

Comment: That should be a comment. It *does* point to the right direction though - with a string field there's no guarantee that all dates have the same format, or even that they *are* dates. Someone could have stored a name in that `val` field

Comment: Weird, when I apply "Try_convert", I do not get any Error:

        row_number() over (Partition by ticket_id Order by convert(datetime,val,104) asc) as nr

Comment: Because NULL normal convert to datetime :)

Comment: @LazlooXp the *bug* is the field type. You didn't post test data or the actual query so it's not possible to say why the query fails. There's no guarantee that `val` contains that format though so you *have* to use `TRY_CONVERT` in the where clause to avoid loading eg names as well as dates. Or fix the bug

Answer (score 1):

I hope your date format is dd.mm.yyyy . so you can below query may help you

```
select convert (datetime ,'15.01.2019 16:58 ',103)
```

In your case

```
row_number() over (Partition by ticket_id Order by convert(datetime,val,103) asc) as nr
```

Comment: Are you trying to say that the correct format is 103 instead of 104? Otherwise this answer is identical to the question's code

Comment: Yep try executing this query select convert (datetime ,'15.01.2019 16:58 ',103)